# Hadoop Uses Wrong Username While Starting It?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-18.04

I have followed the steps here (https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/how-to-install-and-set-up-hadoop-cluster/) in order to setup a multinode hadoop cluster system. I applied the exact same steps.

The name of my nodes:

```
master --> Namenode (Running on my own Ubuntu 18.04 platform)
slave1 --> slave node (data node, Ubuntu 18.04 VM)
slave2 --> slave node (data node, Ubuntu 18.04 VM)
```

slave1 and slave2 runs on two different VMs which has Ubuntu 18.04 on it. The names of the machines and users are also slave1 and slave2. For my own PC, user name is erkan.

The problem is that, when I try to run finally, with using `./start-all.sh` script, it asks me password for erkan@slave1 and erkan@slave2. When I entered the password (passwords are same for all of these) it says wrong password obviously. Because I think that the first name before @ symbol represents the user name which should be slave1 and slave2 in my case(slave1@slave1 and slave2@slave2).

So I probably did some wrong configurations but I could not find what it is. Where can be wrong here?

Comment: You need to use passwordless SSH keys that are copied to all other machines before starting Hadoop. So it shouldn't be prompting for a password at all

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using that, but it is for the user slave1@slave1. Problem is that it does not connect with that ssh. How can I solve this?

Comment: The master connects only using a single user name, I believe. Not a different user for each machine